# Issues with starting an UITest after upgrade to Xamarin Studio version 6.3 (build 864)

Tags: xamarin, uitest

After I have upgraded Xamarin Studio to version 6.3 (build 864) most of the UITests (which have been working fine) are failing. I get the following errors:

1. SetUp : System.Exception : Unable to contact test backend running in app. A common cause is that the app is not properly linked with Calabash. Please verify that it includes the Calabash component.
2. SetUp : Calabash.XDB.Core.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : Failed to install DeviceAgent

ExitCode: 5

```
    -a,--app-path   <path/to/app-bundle.app or path/to/app.ipa> Path .app bundle or .ipa
    -c,--codesign-identity  <codesign-identity> [OPTIONAL]  Identity used to codesign app bundle [device only]. Deprecated - should use profile path.   DEFAULT=
    -d,--device-id  <device-identifier> [OPTIONAL]  iOS Simulator GUIDs
    -p,--profile-path   <path/to/profile.mobileprovision> [OPTIONAL]    Path to provisioning profile
    -u,--update-app <true-or-false> [OPTIONAL]  When true, will reinstall the app if the device contains an older version than the bundle specified DEFAULT=1
install <device_id> <app_id> <profile_path> <codesign_id> <resign_object>
```

Error checking if application is installed: Error Domain=com.facebook.FBSimulatorControl Code=0 "Application with bundle ID 'com.apple.test.DeviceAgent-Runner' is not installed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Application with bundle ID 'com.apple.test.DeviceAgent-Runner' is not installed, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc0d46a88a0 {Error Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=-308 "(ipc/mig) server died"}}

According to error 1: My app is properly linked with calabash, this because it has been working on other versions of Xamarin Studio.

According to error 2: I can see Xamarin has installed the deviceAgent app on the simulator, but for some reason the installation has failed.

Can anyone provide me a solution?

Answer (score -1):

- I have already seen the "Error checking if application is installed:". The issue appeared when iOS 12.0.1 went live because the *Xamarin.UITest* package needed an update (from *Xamarin.UITest* **2.2.6** to **2.2.7**).
- "Unable to connect to testing backend" error might be caused by build configurations, maybe you have some compilation constants(#IF DEBUG) and calabash is started only in Debug mode, while you're trying to run on Release, might be worth checking.
- "Device Agent Failed to install/launch" is a random error that can happen from time to time, when I encounter this I usually fix it:

  - Deleting App and Device Agent and running again
  - Quit Simulator
  - Quit VS and Restart
  - MacBook Restart.

Hope this helps!